# How to return empty array in a case block?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sequelize.js

working on a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html) in Postgres. Currently running into an issue where I'm trying to set a value as either an empty array or an array with just the one `NEW` value, depending on if there is a `NEW` value or not:

```sql
project_ids =
  CASE NEW.project_tracking_id
    WHEN null THEN ARRAY
    ELSE ARRAY[NEW.project_tracking_id]
  END
```

"Set `project_ids` to either `[]` (if null) or `[NEW.project_tracking_id]`"

The else block works as expected and will store that new value as the first element in a new array. The `WHEN null THEN ARRAY` part does not work for me though. It just adds `null` to the array, producing `[null]`.

How do I specify that it should just be an empty array in that case? Not sure if this helps, but my `sequelize` type for that field is:

```js
type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
defaultValue: [],
```

Answer (score 2):

```
project_ids =
  CASE NEW.project_tracking_id
    WHEN null THEN ARRAY[]::XXX[]   //XXX is the type of the array.
    ELSE ARRAY[NEW.project_tracking_id]
  END
```

Comment: This does not work. The result is still an array of `[null]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `CASE` expression implicitly compares `NEW.project_tracking_id = NULL`, which is never true, even if the left side is NULL. Use the other form of `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN NEW.project_tracking_id IS NULL
     THEN ARRAY[]::integer[]
     ELSE ARRAY[NEW.project_tracking_id]
END
```

This assumes that the data type of `NEW.project_tracking_id` is `integer`; change the array type if that is not the case.

A shorter version of the above would be

```
coalesce(NEW.project_tracking_id, ARRAY[]::integer[])
```